# Array structure in datatables

Tags: php, arrays, datatables

How to obtain the following structure after the php json_encode.
It is possible?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750"
    }
  ]
}
```

How must look arrays?

Comment: why after `json_encode`? can't you restructure before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although formally array keys can only be integer you could simple use:

```
array( 'data' => 
    array(
        array( 'name' => 'tiger nixon', 'position' => 'system architect', 'salary' => '$320,800' ), 
        array( 'name' => 'Garrett Winters', 'position' => 'Accountant', 'salary' => '$170,750' )
    )
);
```